# Interesting things about local ring $\mathbb{Z}_{(p)}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

From $\mathbb{Z}$, we obtain a field of fractions $\mathbb{Q}$.

Instead of inverting everything in $\mathbb{Z}$, invert all the members except those which are not multiples of $p$ (i.e. those outside ideal $(p)$). We get what we call a local ring $\mathbb{Z}_{(p)}$. So we have

$$\mathbb{Z} \subseteq \mathbb{Z}_{(p)}\subseteq \mathbb{Q}.$$

I was wondering, what are the interesting properties of $\mathbb{Z}_{(p)}$ which are not true in $\mathbb{Z}$ or $\mathbb{Z}$? For example, consider matrix rings over them:
$$\mathbb{M}_n(\mathbb{Z}) \subseteq \mathbb{M}_n(\mathbb{Z}_{(p)})\subseteq \mathbb{M}_n(\mathbb{Q}).$$
**Q.** What are interesting properties of middle ring which do not hold in two end rings.

[Certainly middle ring is local ring - since two sided ideals in matrix ring are in one-to-one correspondence with two sided ideals of base ring; I will exclude this property of rings in above question.]

Comment: We usually call that ring $\mathbb{Z}_{(p)}$.

Comment: Sorry; I am not too familiar with it; I will edit.

Comment: Unfortunately, I think this question is too broad to answer (though an obvious short answer is: "It is local as you already mentioned"). Note that there is nothing inherently special about the integers for this. We can always make a local ring by inverting everything not in a given prime ideal.